# Reverse engineer Mysql schema to Groovy?

Tags: grails, gradle, groovy, reverse-engineering

I come from using MyEclipse where I can auto generate all my Java Domain/DAO/Hibernate files with a click of a button.  I am trying to find some tools that can do that for a Groovy project.  I know I can use Java classes in Groovy but I don't want to, I need Groovy classes.

Currently I am trying to use Intellij but that only can create Java classes via reverse engineering.

I found a Gradle plugin called `db-reverse-engineer` but that doesn't seem to have the ability to auto detect all my relationships and requires me to manually map them out in a config file before I generate.  This is not acceptable given the sizes of my schemas and the fact I already built the relationships in table, why should I map them out twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The tool to reverse engineer the database to Grails domain classes *IS* db-reverse-engineer.

Regarding the associations (relationships), you'll need to manually configure...

1. The *belongsTo* side of many-to-many associations.
2. Any join tables which have more than two columns.

This is because it's impossible for the tool to reliability choose which domain class *owns* a many-to-many, and because if a join table contains more than two columns the tool cannot be certain that it truly is a join table.

GORM/Hibernate associations and database relationships are similar, but not the same thing. The former is more peculiar.

Comment: That's unfortunate and I wish that `db-reverse-engineer` just did the basic relationships automatically and leave the items you mentioned for manual config.  Perhaps its just because my schemas don't fall under any of those conditions but the Java tools I use reverse engineer everything perfectly.  Oh well, its still better than doing EVERYTHING manual so ill take what I can get.